# Кэширование js и css в Symfony2

Tags: кэширование, javascript, css, php, symfony2

Добрый день.

Не могу понять, почему не кэшируются javascript скрипты и css файлы при запросе от клиента.

Картинки успешно возвращают 304 status и берутся из кэша, js и css всегда возвращают 200.

В symfony2 где-то в конфиге это можно включить?

Пробовал добавить директивы в .htaccess, но тоже безрезультатно.

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
```

Кто-то может подсказать, в чём проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Ставлю традиционные пять баксов, что заголовки отдаются, да только браузер не хочет пользоваться кэшированным контентом, потому что открыт вумещщдыю

Comment: Подумал, что это Symfony2 изгаляется...

Comment: @seqq86, ок, как вы определили наличие бага?

Comment: Как я написал, при просмотре заголоков и статусов, js и css возвращают статус 200. При этом в webtools установлена настройка не отключать кэш (когда открыта панель инструментов).
Может, есть какой-то другой способ проверить, возвращаются ли файлы из кэша?

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```